# ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3

Tags: php, select

Guys I have such datas in the table:: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

query:

```
  SELECT done_sum FROM spent_vs_done WHERE project_id="14" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Results I have right now looks like that:

```
10,9,8
```

I would like to get the last 3 rows like:

```
8,9,10
```

Can you help me to add something to the query to achieve that.

Mysql/PHP

Any help will be Appreciated!!!!

Comment: Use `ASC`  Instead of `DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get ascending order:

```
SELECT t.done_sum
FROM
(
    SELECT done_sum, id
    FROM spent_vs_done
    WHERE project_id="14"
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
ORDER BY t.id
```